# Get datetime on MSSQL

Tags: php, sql-server, sqlsrv

I have a Microsoft database and I make a query that returns a series of values. Everything is fine except when I want to get the date, something does not work and I do not know what it is.

Here is the result of the query:

```
Array ( [0] => DateTime Object ( [date] => 2017-04-10 00:00:00.000000 [timezone_type] => 3 [timezone] => Europe/Berlin ) [1] => DateTime Object ( [date] => 2017-04-10 00:00:00.000000 [timezone_type] => 3 [timezone] => Europe/Berlin ) ) Array ( [0] => DateTime Object ( [date] => 2017-04-07 00:00:00.000000 [timezone_type] => 3 [timezone] => Europe/Berlin ) [1] => DateTime Object ( [date] => 2017-04-07 00:00:00.000000 [timezone_type] => 3 [timezone] => Europe/Berlin ) ) Array ( [0] => DateTime Object ( [date] => 2017-04-04 00:00:00.000000 [timezone_type] => 3 [timezone] => Europe/Berlin ) [1] => DateTime Object ( [date] => 2017-04-04 00:00:00.000000 [timezone_type] => 3 [timezone] => Europe/Berlin ) ) Array ( [0] => DateTime Object ( [date] => 2017-04-10 00:00:00.000000 [timezone_type] => 3 [timezone] => Europe/Berlin ) [1] => DateTime Object ( [date] => 2017-04-10 00:00:00.000000 [timezone_type] => 3 [timezone] => Europe/Berlin ) ) Array ( [0] => DateTime Object ( [date] => 2017-04-10 00:00:00.000000 [timezone_type] => 3 [timezone] => Europe/Berlin ) [1] => DateTime Object ( [date] => 2017-04-10 00:00:00.000000 [timezone_type] => 3 [timezone] => Europe/Berlin ) ) Array ( [0] => DateTime Object ( [date] => 2017-04-07 00:00:00.000000 [timezone_type] => 3 [timezone] => Europe/Berlin ) [1] => DateTime Object ( [date] => 2017-04-07 00:00:00.000000 [timezone_type] => 3 [timezone] => Europe/Berlin ) ) Array ( [0] => DateTime Object ( [date] => 2017-04-10 00:00:00.000000 [timezone_type] => 3 [timezone] => Europe/Berlin ) [1] => DateTime Object ( [date] => 2017-04-10 00:00:00.000000 [timezone_type] => 3 [timezone] => Europe/Berlin ) )
```

How can i get the value of "date"? I try with this but i don't get any result:

```
 echo '</table>';
                 echo '</div>';
                 echo '<div class="tbl-content">';
                 echo '<table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="0">';
                 echo '<tbody>';
                 while ($row = sqlsrv_fetch_array($result)){
                            echo "<tr>";
                            echo "<td>$row[0]</td>";
                            echo "<td>$row[1]</td>";
                            echo "<td>$row[2]</td>";
                            echo "<td>$row[4]</td>";
                            if($row[7]== '1') {
                                echo "<td>Si</td>";
                            } else if($row[7]== '0') {
                                echo "<td>'No'</td>";
                            }
                            echo "<td>$row[5]</td>"; //NO RESULT THERE


                            echo "</tr>";
                        }
                        echo '</tbody>';
                        echo '</table>';
                        echo '</div>';
```

Comment: what did you debug to get that result? its weird that you have a json string as the result when `$row` should be an array

Comment: sorry @Jason Joslin bad copy-paste, now i put the correct text

Comment: Oh i see its returned as datetime object . can you try $row[0]->format('Y/m/d H:i:s')

Answer (score 2, accepted):

PHP objects have their own properties and methods. You cannot simply echo (print) the object and expect to get a string. Checking documentation or `var_dump`ing an object can give you the method or property you should use to access the string value. In this case it is a DateTime object so you should be able to use `DateTime::format('Y-m-d')` to access the date and format it.

> http://php.net/manual/en/book.datetime.php

In your specific case you should be able to use `$row[0]->format('Y/m/d H:i:s')` for each of your date objects to get them as string. Obviously changing the index where applicable.

Comment: Thank you! working flawless, I did not know that we could not directly print a datetime.

Answer (score 1):

As a general rule, you cannot print objects unless they have a [`__toString()` method](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.magic.php#object.tostring) that makes sense. The [`DateTime` class](http://php.net/manual/en/class.datetime.php) doesn't:

```
echo new DateTime();
# Recoverable fatal error: Object of class DateTime could not be converted to string
```

Just [format](http://php.net/datetime_format) to you liking:

```
echo (new DateTime())->format('c');
# 2017-04-11T11:11:28+02:00
echo (new DateTime())->format('r');
# Tue, 11 Apr 2017 11:11:49 +0200
echo (new DateTime())->format('d/m/Y');
# 11/04/2017
```

You're also overlooking that you need to generate HTML, not plain text:

```
echo '<td>' . htmlspecialchars($row[0]->format('d/m/Y')) . '</td>';
```